# Ubuntu Wifi keeps reconnecting even after router reconfiguring

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I have ubuntu 20.04 installed, and, for a specific Wifi connection (the one I have in my home), I have the following problem: the wifi disconnects and reconnects after some time (probably every 3 or 5 minutes).

Here is what I did:

1. I changed the route settings to be as below:

[image]

2. I checked my iwconfig output: as you can see below, the power management is already off

[image]

3. Here is my tail -f /var/log/syslog

```
    Sep  5 08:07:19 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G kernel: [ 1645.645441] wlp3s0: association with b8:d5:26:1b:c9:d2 timed out
    Sep  5 08:07:19 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G wpa_supplicant[1011]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="TISCALI_C9D2" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
    Sep  5 08:07:19 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286039.6381] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
    Sep  5 08:07:19 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286039.6382] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
    Sep  5 08:07:24 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286044.6444] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Sep  5 08:07:24 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286044.6446] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <warn>  [1599286048.1436] device (wlp3s0): link timed out.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286048.1459] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286048.1496] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G gnome-shell[12863]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <warn>  [1599286048.1733] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'TISCALI_C9D2'
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286048.1806] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G avahi-daemon[984]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::486a:a6d:b0f5:5284 on wlp3s0.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G avahi-daemon[984]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::486a:a6d:b0f5:5284.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G avahi-daemon[984]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G gnome-shell[12863]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G gnome-shell[12863]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G dbus-daemon[989]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.9' (uid=0 pid=990 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G google-chrome.desktop[35179]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286048.2275] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286048.2276] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286048.2278] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286048.2278] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> done
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G avahi-daemon[984]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.46 on wlp3s0.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G avahi-daemon[984]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.46.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G avahi-daemon[984]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G dbus-daemon[989]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G gnome-shell[12863]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
    Sep  5 08:07:28 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G gnome-shell[12863]: message repeated 5 times: [ An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?]
    Sep  5 08:07:29 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286049.2172] policy: auto-activating connection 'TISCALI_C9D2' (3a893e63-7e87-40eb-afd9-4c7549434712)
    Sep  5 08:07:29 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286049.2178] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'TISCALI_C9D2' (3a893e63-7e87-40eb-afd9-4c7549434712)
    Sep  5 08:07:29 myusername-Aspire-E5-574G NetworkManager[990]: <info>  [1599286049.2179] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

This does not happen in any other wifi connection and my windows and Android devices work perfectly in the same Wifi network. Is there any configuration I must do to get my Ubuntu working in my wifi?

Comment: open nm-connection-editor and delete the WiFi and then try connect again to the same WiFi

Comment: @kannzzmm2 it seems that it worked, if you want to answer it will be my pleasure to mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and changing router configuration, I assumed that the WiFi configuration has not been properly changed in Network Manager. The solution to this problem is simple just by:

1. opening `nm-connection-editor` on Terminal
2. Select and Delete the WiFi Connection
3. Connect to the same WiFi from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

[kanzzmm2](https://askubuntu.com/users/823951/kannzzmm2) answer is correct.

I would Add only one step: restart NetworkManager. Only after this step my network get back to stability.

I'm using 20.04.5 LTS with a MESH setup.