# Connection failed activation of network connection failed on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

I have a netbook that I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto. Ethernet works, but Wifi is unable to connect to our home network. What is even more baffling is that we were able to have the laptop connect to an iPhone hotspot and access the internet.

Our home wifi network is the problem. We have probably a dozen devices (phones, laptops, desktops, smart devices) connected to the network, so it can't possibly be an IP address exhaustion issue. We've tried all the solutions in the following page [LINK](https://appuals.com/activation-of-network-connection-failed-in-linux/) (e.g. reinstall network devices, restart network devices, restart computer, `apt-get update` numerous times) but nothing panned out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to delete the wifi connection in nm-connection-editor and try again to connect to the wifi
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272770/ubuntu-wifi-keeps-reconnecting-even-after-router-reconfiguring?noredirect=1#comment2156505_1272770

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.